# Check if multiple files are present in particular location if yes then proceed with the code else re run the above code

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, jupyter-notebook

Consider i have 5 files in 5 different location.
Example  = fileA in XYZ location
fileB in ZXC location
fileC in XBN location so on

I want to check if these files are actually saved in that location if they are not re run the code above that saves the file.

Ex:

```
if:
 fileA, fileB so on are present in their particular location  the proceed with code further 
else:
re run the file saving code above
```

How do i do this in python i am not able to figure out.

Comment: I guess you could store the map of `files` and `paths` as a list of tuple: mfiles = (fileA, XYZ), ..., (fileZ, ABC)]. Then you can loop over that list and then on each iteration you can check if `glob.glob(os.path.join(f, p))`  (where f is file and p is path) is not empty and if it is then go to your other condition

Comment: Try to implement a solution with the given suggestions and if that doesn't work, post your code as an update and ask your questions there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store all your files with their locations in a list and then iterate all locations for existence then you can decide further what to do.

A Python example:

```py
from os.path import exists

# all files to check in different locations
locations = [
    '/some/location/xyz/fileA',
    '/other/location/fileB',
    '/yet/another/location/fileC',
]

# iterate to check each file existance
status = [exists(location) for location in locations]

# check the status of all files
# if any of the files doesn't exist, else will be called
if(all(status)):
    print('All files are present.')
else:
    print('Any or all files do not exist.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a python dev, and I just wanted try to contribute  to the community.
The first answer is way better than mine, but I'd like to share my solution for that question.

You could use `sys` to pass the files' names, inside a `try` block to handle when the files are not found.
If you run the script from a location while the files are at another location, it would be needed to provide their path.
`check.py ../test1.txt ../test2.txt ../test3.txt`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os.path
import sys

try:
    fpath = sys.argv[1]
    fpath = sys.argv[2]
    fpath = sys.argv[3]
    if (os.path.isfile(fpath)) != "":
        print("Exists on system")
    else:
        pass
except IndexError:
    for i in range(3):
        file1 = "test1.txt"
        file2 = "test2.txt"
        file3 = "test3.txt"
        sys.stdout = open(file1, "w")
        print("Saving content to files")
        sys.stdout = open(file2, "w")
        print("Saving content to files")
        sys.stdout = open(file3, "w")
        print("Saving content to files")
```

The `exception` part would then "save" the files, by creating new ones, writing whatever content you desire.